# GridComponent not working when deployed with ng build

Tags: angular, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

In my app, I am using syncfusion component for grids in angular. It all works fine while im serving my app with ng serve localy.
But when I deploy my app with ng build and run it on server via nginx.exe, all grid components don't work. Instead of tables, there is just syncfusions spinner "spinning" in their place.

I have same problem with @agm/core.

Comment: Have you include all css ?

Comment: I have 10 imports of css in styles.css, all listed by their guide

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved by doing steps below.

1. Delete package.lock.json file
2. Remove the @syncfusion package folder from the node_modules.
3. Use latest version or “*”(Installs the latest packages) for all Syncfusion components in package.json file.
4. Then install the NPM packages.